# How to get the max row number from a table by using linq

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ColumnName) + 1, 1) AS ColumnName 
FROM TableName
```

How to write this query in **LINQ**.Is there any way to convert sql to linq . i want a converter.

Above query works well but i want the same output on linq .**How to ?**

**I know how to select max**

```
  var products = ((from p in db.TableName
                            select p.ColumnName).Max());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
return (myContext.MyTable.Max(t => (int?) t.MyColumn) ?? 0) + 1
```

Comment: above syntax show me error "operator ?? can not be applied of operands of type int and int"

Comment: I thought your column was nullable. Try the modified syntax with the `int?` cast.

Comment: thanks.it's really helpful for me thanks again.Now if i want to set Table and column name dynamically in linq how to do that.Suppose,My method contain table name and column name How to use them on the above syntax